# Office 365 Excel Formula - Is there anything that I missed out on the REDUCE() formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Edit:

### Please note that usage of REDUCE() is a must, it is the main point of this question

The element doubling is just an example, it can be other kind of operations, which would be put into the LAMBDA function

---

I want to do something like projecting/inflatting an array to another in a complex way

But to start simple let's say what I want to do is to double the elements of an array:

```
{1,2,5,4} => {1,1,2,2,5,5,4,4}
```

Just a walk in the park of Python, Power Query etc, I thought.

Turns out that I was spending lots of time to find out how to create an empty array as the initial value to be supplied to `HSTACK()`, something like:

```
# No such thing as {} in Excel Formulas
=REDUCE({},{1,2,5,4},LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a, HSTACK(b,b))))
```

... and after realizing that it is not possible, I have to give it a placeholder and then remove it afterwards:

```
=DROP(REDUCE("foo",{1,2,5,4},LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a, HSTACK(b,b)))),,1)
```

Is it the only way to do so? Awkward if you ask me.

Comment: Why are you  so focused on the reduce()  function when it is clearly not needed? Unless this is an assignment or homework??

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LET`:

Input = vertical array
`=LET(d,{1;2;5;4},TOROW(HSTACK(d,d)))`

Input = horizontal array
`=LET(d,{1,2,5,4},TOROW(VSTACK(d,d),,TRUE))`

Comment: @jvdv - could this be a language specific thing: in German Excel I need to use semicolon to get a vertical array, dots to get a horizontal array. So for a German Excel I need to set the semicolon - otherwise the sort order is not correct ...

Comment: Upvoted, but it would not yet return `{1,1,2,2,5,5,4,4}`. For that to happen you would need to `VSTACK()`and then use `1` as the 3rd parameter in `TOROW()`. Something like: `=LET(d,{1,2,5,4},TOROW(VSTACK(d,d),,1))`

Comment: Absolutely a language thing, however your formula was correct for German, OP's input is a horizontal range where delimiter is a comma instead of semi-colon. Hope you don't mind the correction.

Answer (score 1):

As to why `REDUCE()` behaves like it does; without a 1st parameter it will use the 1st value of the array in the 2nd parameter in the 1st iteration. See linked dupe.

---

My two cents regarding this test-case is to avoid `LAMBDA()`. Just some array manipulations:

[image]

```
=LET(input,{1,2,5,4},times,2,TOROW(IFNA(EXPAND(input,times),input),,1))
```

This does assume you have input as an horizontal array/range though. If `REDUCE()` is a must, you can use:

```
=LET(input,{1,2,5,4},times,2,TOROW(REDUCE(input,SEQUENCE(times-1),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,input))),,1))
```

Comment: I can't see why it would be a must if there are simpler and quicker ways, but see the edit @im_chc

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, without using <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=LET(x,{1,2,5,4},n,2,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",,REPT(x&"|",n)),"|",,1))
```

---

Update: as OP edited post with <kbd>REDUCE</kbd> is a must:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=TOROW(DROP(REDUCE("",{1,2,5,4},LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,EXPAND(y,2,,y)))),1))
```

---

Comment: @im_chc just updated answer.